# Function that creates an additional (dummy) column for each column that contains NA (in R)

Tags: r, na

I seem to be unable to wrap my head around this:  I have an R dataset (`data.frame`) with a good amount of columns that contain `NA`s.  I would like to create an additional column for *each* column that contains `NA`.  I would like the additional column to be a dummy column that is `1` if `NA` and `0` else.  Of course, I could do things manually for each column but that would just be a pain ... however, by now I should have probably done so.  I have tried playing around with `plyr` but am unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example and your attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map` to associate your new column close to the original column of your `data.frame`:

```
do.call(cbind, Map(function(u,v) data.frame(u,v), df, data.frame(is.na(df)+0L)))

#  col1.u col1.v col2.u col2.v
#1   <NA>      1     NA      1
#2      a      0     NA      1
#3      b      0     NA      1
#4   <NA>      1     33      0
```

**Data:**

```
df = data.frame(col1=c(NA,'a','b',NA), col2=c(NA,NA,NA,33))
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE), 10, 10))
is.na(df)*1 # dummy data.frame
```